# handle print, Change script from local server to hosting

Tags: php, printing, handle

```
<?php
    /*
     *  handle printer
     */
    if($prints['computer_ip'] == '127.0.0.1'){
        $printer_name = (string)$prints['printer_name'];
    }else{
        $printer_name = "\\\\" . (string)$prints['computer_ip'] . "\\" . (string)$prints['printer_name'];
    }

    $handle = printer_open($printer_name);

    if($handle){
        printer_start_doc($handle, "Receipt");
        printer_start_page($handle);

        $pen = printer_create_pen(PRINTER_PEN_SOLID, 1, "000000");
        printer_select_pen($handle, $pen);

        $font= printer_create_font($prints['font_name'], (int)$prints['font_height'], (int)$prints['font_width'], 100, false, false, false, 0);
        printer_select_font($handle, $font);

        $paper_width        = (int)$prints_option['page_width'];
        $width              = (int)$prints_option['width'];
        $left               = ($paper_width - $width)/2;        
        $posisi_y_print     = (int)$prints_option['top'];
        $posisi_y_berikutnya = (int)$prints['font_height'];
```

Comment: You can't print from the client's computer using PHP, since PHP runs on the server. You need to use `window.print()` from Javascript.

Comment: but when i use window.print() i print everything in web... i need some element to be print, anyone can help me?

Comment: Use `@media print` in your CSS to control which elements are printed and how they look.

Comment: @barmar: please give me and example

Answer (score 0):

You cant't print page from client side. You need to applies Javascript window.print() or jquery [Page print](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/print/)
print plugins. Also you can use [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) or [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php) for PDF creation from server side.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change how the page appears when it's printed, use a CSS media query. E.g. if there's are some elements that should not be displayed when printing, and others that should only be displayed when printing, use:

```
.printOnly {
    display: none;
}

@media print {

    .noprint {
        display: none;
    }

    .printOnly {
        display: block;
    }

}
```

And give those elements `class="noprint"` or `class="printOnly"`.

Comment: may i know your email??? i want to send you my complete script, i i hope you want to change it, course i can't apply your script to my script... thanks

Comment: Sorry, I have enough work to do, I'm not going to do your work for you.